# Paging data upt to 10 rows, using load more in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I'm training on how to make loadmore using the retrofit library based on this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRhwEdGoo8c. but the problem is that I want to display data per 10 and then load appears and then data appears again per 10 and so on.
I enclose the following code:

PaginationScrollListener:

```
package com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.utils;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public abstract class PaginationScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    public PaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                    && totalItemCount >= getTotalPageCount()) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }

    }

    protected abstract void loadMoreItems();

    public abstract int getTotalPageCount();

    public abstract boolean isLastPage();

    public abstract boolean isLoading();
}
```

Adapter:

```
package com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.R;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.models.FilmPria;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilmPriaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int ITEM = 0;
    private static final int LOADING = 1;
    private static final String BASE_URL_IMG = "http://192.168.0.41:8000/images/";

    private List<FilmPria> filmPriaResults;
    private Context context;

    private boolean isLoadingAdded = false;

    public FilmPriaAdapter (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        filmPriaResults = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<FilmPria> getFilmPria() {
        return filmPriaResults;
    }

    public void setFilmPria(List<FilmPria> filmPriaResults) {
        this.filmPriaResults = filmPriaResults;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case ITEM:
                viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, inflater);
                break;
            case LOADING:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_progressbar, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new LoadingViewHolder(v2);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @NonNull
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_film_pria, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new FilmPriaHolder(v1);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FilmPria result = filmPriaResults.get(position);
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case ITEM:
                FilmPriaHolder filmPriaHolder = (FilmPriaHolder) holder;
                filmPriaHolder.tvArtistName.setText(result.getArtistName());
                filmPriaHolder.tvAge.setText("Usia : "+result.getAge());
                filmPriaHolder.tvHeight.setText("Tinggi : "+result.getHeight());
                filmPriaHolder.tvWeight.setText("Berat : "+result.getWeight());
                filmPriaHolder.tvDomicile.setText("Domisili : "+result.getDomicile());
                Glide
                        .with(context)
                        .load(BASE_URL_IMG + result.getPhoto())
                        .addListener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                //filmPriaHolder..setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                //filmPriaHolder.ivArtistName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)   // cache both original & resized image
                        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                        .error(R.drawable.pria)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.pria)
                        .into(filmPriaHolder.ivArtistName);

                break;

            case LOADING:
            //Do nothing
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filmPriaResults== null ? 0 : filmPriaResults.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == filmPriaResults.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) ? LOADING : ITEM;
    }

    public void add(FilmPria r) {
        filmPriaResults.add(r);
        notifyItemInserted(filmPriaResults.size() - 1);
    }

    public void addAll(List<FilmPria> filmPriaResults) {
        for (FilmPria result : filmPriaResults) {
            add(result);
        }
    }

    public void addLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = true;
        add(new FilmPria());
    }

    public void removeLoadingFooter() {
        isLoadingAdded = false;

        int position = filmPriaResults.size() - 1;
        FilmPria result = getItem(position);

        if (result != null) {
            filmPriaResults.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public FilmPria getItem(int position) {
        return filmPriaResults.get(position);
    }

    public class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.footerProgressBar) ProgressBar footerProgressBar;

        public LoadingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    public class FilmPriaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.tvArtistName) TextView tvArtistName;
        @BindView(R.id.tvAge) TextView tvAge;
        @BindView(R.id.tvHeight) TextView tvHeight;
        @BindView(R.id.tvWeight) TextView tvWeight;
        @BindView(R.id.tvDomicile) TextView tvDomicile;
        @BindView(R.id.ivArtistName) ImageView ivArtistName;
        public FilmPriaHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

and Fragment:

```
package com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.ui;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.R;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.adapters.FilmPriaAdapter;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.apis.Client;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.apis.ServiceFilmPria;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.models.FilmPria;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.models.FilmPriaResponse;
import com.dekikurnia.appcelebrity.utils.PaginationScrollListener;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilmPriaFragment extends Fragment{

    @BindView(R.id.rvFilmPria)
    RecyclerView rvFilmPria;
    @BindView(R.id.progressBar)
    ProgressBar pbLoading;
    FilmPriaAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    List<FilmPria> filmPria = new ArrayList<>();

    private String TAG = "FilmPriaFragment";

    private static final int PAGE_START = 1;
    private boolean isLoading = false;
    private boolean isLastPage = false;
    private int TOTAL_PAGES = 5;
    private int currentPage = PAGE_START;

    private ServiceFilmPria filmPriaService;

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_film_pria, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        adapter = new FilmPriaAdapter(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvFilmPria.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        rvFilmPria.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rvFilmPria.setAdapter(adapter);

        rvFilmPria.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            protected void loadMoreItems() {
                isLoading = true;
                currentPage += 1;

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loadNextPage();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public int getTotalPageCount() {
                return TOTAL_PAGES;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLastPage() {
                return isLastPage;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLoading() {
                return isLoading;
            }
        });

        filmPriaService = Client.getClient().create(ServiceFilmPria.class);

        loadFirstPage();

        return view;
    }

    private void loadFirstPage() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadFirstPage: ");

        callFilmPriaApi().enqueue(new Callback<FilmPriaResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FilmPriaResponse> call, Response<FilmPriaResponse> response) {

                List<FilmPria> results = fetchResults(response);
                pbLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                adapter.addAll(results);

                if (currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) {
                    adapter.addLoadingFooter();
                } else {
                    isLastPage = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FilmPriaResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error fetching Profile Pemain Film Pria",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private List<FilmPria> fetchResults(Response<FilmPriaResponse> response) {
        FilmPriaResponse filmPriaResponse = response.body();
        return filmPriaResponse.getData();
    }

    private void loadNextPage() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadNextPage: " + currentPage);

        callFilmPriaApi().enqueue(new Callback<FilmPriaResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FilmPriaResponse> call, Response<FilmPriaResponse> response) {
                adapter.removeLoadingFooter();
                isLoading = false;

                List<FilmPria> results = fetchResults(response);
                adapter.addAll(results);

                if (currentPage != TOTAL_PAGES) {
                    adapter.addLoadingFooter();
                } else {
                    isLastPage = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FilmPriaResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error fetching Profile Pemain Film Pria",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private Call<FilmPriaResponse> callFilmPriaApi() {
        return filmPriaService.getFilmPria(
                currentPage
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
public class LazyLading extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    /*Page Size*/
    public static final Integer FIRST_INDEX = 1;
    private static final Integer PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.

    private int pageIndex = FIRST_INDEX;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private LazyLadingListener listener;

    public LazyLading(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager, LazyLadingListener listener) {
        mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        /*Pagination Conditions*/
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        int visibleThreshold = 3;
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached
            // Do something
            pageIndex++;

            listener.onLoadMore(pageIndex);

            loading = true;
        }

    }

    public void reset() {
        previousTotal = PAGE_SIZE;
        pageIndex = FIRST_INDEX;
        loading = false;
    }

    public interface LazyLadingListener {
        void onLoadMore(int pageIndex);
    }

}
```

for using this classs

```
lazyLading = new LazyLading(layoutManager, this);
```

dont forget to reset your lazylading on refresh of RecyclerView

```
lazyLading.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading implementation with custom library or helper when load more received at the end of list

```
abstract class EndlessListener(private val carouselLayoutManager: CarouselLayoutManager) :
    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    private val visibleThreshold = 5
    private var currentPage = 0
    private var previousTotalItemCount = 0
    private var loading = true
    private var startingPageIndex = 0

    fun getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions: IntArray): Int {
        var maxSize = 0
        for (i in lastVisibleItemPositions.indices) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i]
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i]
            }
        }
        return maxSize
    }

    override fun onScrolled(view: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        val lastVisibleItemPosition = (carouselLayoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition()
        val totalItemCount = carouselLayoutManager.itemCount

        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            currentPage = startingPageIndex
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                loading = true
            }
        }

        if (loading && totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount) {
            loading = false
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount
        }

        if (!loading && lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold > totalItemCount) {
            currentPage++
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view)
            loading = true
        }
    }

    fun resetState() {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex
        this.previousTotalItemCount = 0
        this.loading = true
    }

    abstract fun onLoadMore(page: Int, totalItemsCount: Int, view: RecyclerView)

}
```

And add a listener for change scroll position

```
 recycelerView.addOnScrollListener(object : EndlessListener(layoutManager) {
                override fun onLoadMore(page: Int, totalItemsCount: Int, view: RecyclerView) {

                }
            })
```